# Every 2 mins I get a notification says my number "will continue to be registered for iMessage and FaceTime. You can change this in Message Settings"

Tags: iphone, apple-id, facetime, sim

It says the following when I open the notificiation.

> This number is registered to your Apple ID, but is not associated with this phone. You can keep using the number for iMessage and FaceTime until it expires.

Recently I added a eSim. I converted the plan on my original SIM to talk + text only because my eSim now have more than enough data. I'm roaming in another country for the long-term so I figured this was the best move forward.

So in 27 days, I will no longer be able to iMessage from this number? It's odd because it's still my number and it should still be associated with my phone. I still get SMS texts to my phone daily, and calls as well.

Any idea what to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you do?